# How can I use the Android Management API to lock down a device to only one application without an EMM Console or any subscribed service?

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-enterprise

I'm looking to leverage the Android Management API to lock down an Android device to only one application without the need for an EMM Console or any subscribed service. Could someone provide a step-by-step guide or code example on how to achieve this using the Android Management API?

Thank you.

I've tried reading the API's documentation, but I'm having trouble understanding where to start and what to do.

Answer (score 1):

To lock down an Android device to only one application using the Android Management API, you should implement [Kiosk Mode](https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices#kiosk_mode) in your application policy:

```
{
  "applications":  [
    {
      "packageName":  "com.example.yourapp",
      "installType":  "KIOSK"
    }
  ]
}
```

Replace "com.example.yourapp" with the package name of your desired application.
You may follow the [Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart) to guide you on how to get started with the Android Management API. Follow the steps below to enroll an enterprise, create a policy, and provision a device.